# Automatically click website buttons like selenium

Tags: selenium, curl

I have a project that requires automating a process on a website (login, click buttons, make decisions, etc.).

Ordinarily I would use something like curl to do the automation and not worry about the UI at all, however this site uses ASPX and redirects and is just a mess, so I need to write something like a selenium test to do it.

A selenium seems like a bit of a hack though, so I was wondering if there is any alternative or tool that may be better than selenium at walking the dom and "clicking" elements?

Guidance or examples appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non programtic way would be to use [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/). Basically you record the events via a Firefox extension and can replay easily. I understand this is a non automating way as it requires a manual playback.

However one element that I really like is that I can use this extension to record my events and then generate scripts to automate playback via `Selenium Remote Control` [drivers](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp#programming-languages).

> Selenium IDE is an integrated development environment for Selenium
>   scripts. It is implemented as a Firefox extension, and allows you to
>   record, edit, and debug tests. Selenium IDE includes the entire
>   Selenium Core, allowing you to easily and quickly record and play back
>   tests in the actual environment that they will run in.

Yes I know you think selenium is a hack but it is rather pretty good!

Comment: I think its cool too! I only ever used it for automated GUI testing though, and didn't know if it was also a good tool for my problem :)